# Python subprocess not seing same files as cmd.exe

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I'm not sure exactly how to proceed at this point, so here is my situation.

If I start elevated `cmd.exe`, and navigate to `C:\Windows\system32`, I can perform the following command: `dir /B | findstr /R /C:"bash"` and `bash.exe` is the output.

However, if I start elevated `cmd.exe`, then run `python` (3.5.1) and do the following:

```
import subprocess
import os
subprocess.Popen("start", env=os.environ, Shell=True)
```

I get an elevated shell which does not recognize the existence of `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`; that is when I perform `dir /B | findstr /R /C:"bash"` in the at directory I get **no output.**

Since these prompts are all elevated I couldn't imagine it being a permissions problem. I've attached a picture wherein, the left side is a normal elevated command prompt and the right side is the python situation I just described.

Thanks,
MadcowD

[image: The error occurring across two different command prompts.]

Comment: Sounds like you are running a 32-bit Python program on a 64-bit version of Windows. From a 32-bit console, when you navigate to *system32*, you are really looking at *SysWOW64*. See [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx) for more information.

Comment: @Avia I started the python process in `C:\Windows\System32`, and just tried doing it in a different directory and then navigating there, still no change. Have any thoughts, or am I interpreting your response wrong.

Comment: You're using 32-bit Python, which redirects accessing "System32" to "SysWOW64" and so starts 32-bit cmd.exe. Change to the virtual directory "C:\Windows\SysNative", which is the native 64-bit "System32" directory.

Comment: @eryksun ive battled this before I did not realize you could access that alternative directory ... thats awesome

Comment: Start isn't a program that's why it can't find it. It's an internal command used for starting programs in unusual ways. Therefore it probably isn't needed.

Comment: @Noodles That's actually not the problem at all. Changing to 64-bit python solved the issue entirely. Also @eryksun's `C:\Windows\SysNative\` solved the issue on 32-bit.

Comment: You said when 32 vs 64 was mentioned that it didn't apply *and just tried doing it in a different directory and then navigating there, still no change*.

Comment: @Noodles: I reckon he meant "starting with a different initial current directory, then navigating to system32".  Also, using `start` in this context is an easy way to create an interactive console window that the parent process wont' wait on, so is probably intentional.